# What's the URL on a Mac to refer to a directory on a networked Windows machine?

Tags: windows-10, mac

I'm trying to checkout a repository hosted on a Windows machine on my local area network.  I'm new to mac and can't figure out the correct path name.  I've mapped my windows machine under the name //bananas and the repo is called mySvnRepo.  However, `file://\\bananas\mySvnRepo` is not working.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need Samba set up on your Mac.  URL would look like `smb://server/fileshare` or `cifs://server/fileshare` possibly.

Comment: how were the files shared?  through file & sharing?  or through a web server?

Comment: @ivanivan macOS has a built-in SMB implementation. It does not need Samba.

Comment: Note that Mac doesn't use NetBIOS name resolution (for finding servers), so it may not recognize the same server name that your Windows computers use.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have one of the more recent versions of macOS you can connect to any Windows share fairly simply.

1. In Finder go to (the menu) Go > Connect to server
2. Enter smb://servername/name/of/share/
3. macOS will pop up a dialog asking for username and password
4. Enter your **FULLY QUALIFIED** username (domain\username) or (PC Name\username) and then your password on that PC or in that domain.

That should get you in.

It is important that if that Windows server is set up in an AD domain that you user the domain name, a backslash and your username in the domain and then your domain password.

If the Windows server is not a member of an AD domain substitute the network name of the server (sometimes called the NETBIOS name).

Remember that you have to use credentials from your Windows server **NOT** your Mac as you are authenticating on your server *through* the Mac (which is just sending the credentials to the Windows server)

BTW if the server name does not work, just use the IP address of the Windows server in its place.